# How can I get language setting of iPhone as Unity3D native function?

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine

I've try everything to find a way to get the language setting of iPhone via a native Unity3D function. however, I found two ways, those are:

1) use `guiText.text = Application.systemLanguage.ToString();`
But I always get 'Unknown' in Chinese language.
2) use NSUserDefaults and PlayerPrefs.
But it's not a Unity3D native function, I'll have to do some extra work when I want to develop my Android version.

So, anyone can please show me: Is there a PERFECT way to do that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what unity is, but would NSLocale or CFLocale help you?  NSLocale is objective-c based and thus a bit easier to use:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html

CFLocale is c-based, so its a bit more tricky, but offers more functionality:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFLocaleRef/Reference/reference.html

If you are looking for the current language code you should be able to grab the current locale and inspect that.

Comment: Thank you darren, Unity3D is a game engine. as those in my question, I've already know how to get it in cocoa. I just want to know if there is any way to get the language setting in Unity3D native function. anyway, thanks a lot.